# RxJs catchError changes return type

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, angular13

I'm trying to implement some caching and I have the below method. The `catchError` block is causing an error because the return type becomes `Observable<Client | Client[]>`.  I'm not seeing why it thinks it's not an array of client, or how to fix.

```js
#clients: Client[] = []
#clientsLastModified: string | null = null


index(): Observable<Client[]> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
    if (this.#clientsLastModified)
        headers = headers.set('If-Modified-Since', this.#clientsLastModified)

    return this.http.get<IClientDTO[]>('clients', {headers, observe: 'response'}).pipe(
        map(x => {
            this.#clientsLastModified = x.headers.get('Last-Modified')

            if (x.status === HttpStatusCode.Ok && x.body) {
                this.#clients = x.body.map(x => new Client(x))
                return this.#clients
            } else
                return of([])
        }),
        catchError((err: unknown) => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === HttpStatusCode.NotModified)
                return this.#clients

            return throwError(() => err)
        })
    )
}
```

Comment: try returning a observable in the catch error, like return of(this.#clients)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two small changes to make to get this corrected:

1. don't use `of` inside your map. You want the result of your map to return type `Client[]`; `of` makes it return `Observable<Client[]>`
2. use `of` inside `catchError`. Inside `catchError`, you should return observable, so `of` is needed.  The reason no error is shown is because the type is Array, and Array is also a vaild [`ObservableInput`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js%7EObservableInputDoc.html), but will have different behavior.  RxJS will convert Array to an observable that emits each item individually (*thus the type ends up being `Observable<Client>` instead of `Observable<Client[]>`*).

```js
return this.http.get<IClientDTO[]>('clients', {headers, observe: 'response'}).pipe(
  map(x => {
    this.#clientsLastModified = x.headers.get('Last-Modified')

    if (x.status === HttpStatusCode.Ok && x.body) {
      this.#clients = x.body.map(x => new Client(x))
        return this.#clients
      } else
        return [] // <-- don't use of
  }),
  catchError((err: unknown) => {
    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === HttpStatusCode.NotModified)
      return of(this.#clients) // <-- use of

      return throwError(() => err)
  })
)
```

Comment: Great explanation, thank you!